# External Method Parameters Definition Issue

Tags: c#

*I am trying to learn about External Methods*. Lets say there is an extension method like this:

```
static class clsExtensionMethods
    {
        public static  int GetFulLNameLength
            (this clsPerson xxx, //<-- what is xxx for?
            string parmFirstName, 
            string parmLastName)

        {
            Console.WriteLine(xxx); //<-- shows: "Generic_tests.clsPerson" at run-time
            return parmFirstName.Length + parmLastName.Length; }
        }
```

This method is called like this (**it compiles and executes fine**):

```
        clsPerson p1 = new clsPerson();
        p1.firstName = "G.";
        p1.lastName = "Bush";
        Console.WriteLine(p1.GetFulLNameLength(p1.firstName, p1.lastName));
```

What is the role of the parameter called xxx in the above example?
It is mandatory for the code to compile, yet it is not passed any data and it gets no data from the explicit code.
The function is called with 2 variables.

Edit:

Also non of the following forms compile because xxx is considered to be not defined (all code is the same namespace)

```
 xxx((p1.firstName, p1.lastName)
```

or

```
 p1.xxx((p1.firstName, p1.lastName)
```

or

```
 clsPerson.xxx(p1.firstName, p1.lastName)
```

So, I am not sure what is the role of xxx exactly in this case, or how to utilize it.

Environment: .NET 6.0, Windows 11, VS 2022

Comment: I think you need to read about extension methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods   `xxx` is just the name of your "this" parameter.

Comment: @KirkWoll, thanks for the comment, I did read a bit about subject and it is somewhat confusing to me.

Comment: For your specific example, you'd omit the `parmFirstName` and `parmLastName` parameters, as they are already contained in `clsPerson`.  And your implementation would simply be `return xxx.firstName.Length + xxx.lastName.Length;`.  It allows you to "tack on" methods to a foreign class when that class has all the data you need to implement your new method.

Comment: @KirkWoll, sounds fair However, I wanted to learn about passing parameters...

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you for your message, I get the concept and the link is good but for some reason it does not apply to my case though it should.

Comment: You appear to be confused: `xxx` is your `this` parameter, not the name of the method. You would instead do `xxx.GetFulLNameLength(someFirstName, someLastName)`. I must say, it doesn't make a huge amount of sense to pass in parameters which are part of the `this` anyway, as the method will be able to access it anyway. What exactly about that post does not apply here?

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you for the link, it discusses single parameter and I am confused about the syntax. Well, I need to study this more. I will close the issue for now.